# How to fetch data from objects in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am doing a simple cart system.

I created a table to display the products with add to cart button on the side of every product. I was able to get the index of every product when I click the button but I can't fetch the data inside the object(the name, price, and qty). Please help! How can I get them? Thanks.

```js
< script >
  var app = angular.module("shoppingCart", []);
app.controller("cartCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.products = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Baby Mix Lobster (300g - down)',
      unit: 'per kg',
      price: 2500,
      qty: 1
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Tiger Lobster (1kg - up)',
      unit: 'per kg',
      price: 5800,
      qty: 1
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Tiger Lobster (700g - 999g)',
      unit: 'per kg',
      price: 4500,
      qty: 1
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Tiger Lobster (500g-699g)',
      unit: 'per kg',
      price: 4200,
      qty: 1
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: 'Tiger Lobster (300g-499g)',
      unit: 'per kg',
      price: 3900,
      qty: 1
    },

  ];




  $scope.addToCart = function(item) {

    alert(item);

  }



});

<
/script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>




  <table style="border: 1px solid black">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>unit</th>
      <th>price</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in products">
      <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
      <td>{{x.name}}</td>
      <td>{{x.unit}}</td>
      <td>{{x.price | currency: "Php " : 2}}</td>
      <td><input type="number" min="1" placeholder="{{x.qty}}" /></td>
      <td><button ng-click="addToCart($index)">Add to Cart</button></td>

    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't you add to the cart based on the id number rather than an arbitrary incremental index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to pass the item `x` instead of the `index`

```
ng-click="addToCart(x)"
```

Comment: I was trying to fetch the data using the index. Heheh. Your solution works too man, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Kkk no problem. Make sure to check as answer if this helped

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to get the index, then why not fetch the object from the array?

```
$scope.addToCart = function(index) {
    var item = $scope.products[index];
    // access the properties of `item` here.
}
```

Also, it is recommended to track the items of `ng-repeat`:

```
ng-repeat="x in products track by $index"
```

Comment: Didn't know that I have to put it in a variable. I am fetching it directly like this

$scope.addToCart = function(index) {
    $scope.products.name[item];
}

Thanks a lot man! Your solution works. I can fetch the data now.